# Make Tensorflow Ignore Values

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a convolutional network in Python and Tensorflow. The out put will be the bounding boxes of the detected objects. I have made the output a 20 x 20 grid and each grid will detect a bounding box together with the probability. So my output will be 20 x 20 x 5.

20 x 20 for the grid

5 for probability + center within the grid (x, y) + height + width of bounding box

When there are no objects within a grid box the probability is zero and the bounding box values should be don't care values.

My question is how do I define the output with don't care values. That is Tensorflow should exclude these in the cost calculation. If I use zero that would be so wrong as I would be telling Tensorfow that there is a 0 x 0 box. So how do I define don't care values?

Comment: Have you read the Fast/Faster R-CNN or YOLO papers? If not, that is your starting point.

Comment: Not yet. Will give it a go . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. If there is a more efficient way would like to learn.

```
mask = tf.tile(Y[:, :, :, 0:1], [1, 1, 1, 5]) #repeating the first item 5 times
mask_first = tf.tile(Y[:, :, :, 0:1], [1, 1, 1, 1]) #repeating the first item 1 time

mask_of_ones = tf.ones(tf.shape(mask_first))

full_mask = tf.concat([tf.to_float(mask_of_ones), tf.to_float(mask[:, :, :, 1:])], 3)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.multiply(full_mask, tf.to_float(tf.subtract(Y_hat, Y, name="cost")))))
```